# HTTPS on Bitbucket server server certificate verification failed when git clone

Tags: ssl, https, server.xml, bitbucket-server

when I try to clone on bitbcuket server only have the HTTP Option and on my server.xml I configured the ssl:
server.xml :

```
<Connector port="8443" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true"
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS"
redirectPort="443"
proxyName="dev-services.domainname.es"
proxyPort="443"
keystorePass="keystorePassword"
keyPass="keyPassword"
keyAlias="le-55fd1606-33ed-47fd-b23c-11443dc6f5ec"
keystoreFile="/etc/nginx/cert/bitbucket.jks" />
```

we have a nginx running and configuration is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name dev-services.domainname.es;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/cert.rsa;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  location /
  { 
     proxy_pass https://localhost:8443;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-   Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

All works fine but when we try to make git clone It shows:
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/nginx/cert/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

And when we go to clone on the bitbucket server we only have http (inside has https)
[image]

NOTE: we have a wildcard certificate "*.domainname.es"

Comment: if we try to git clone on the server then: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP here, perhaps confusingly, refers to both HTTP and HTTPS in this case (as opposed to SSH) - the actual URL reflects the right thing.

Comment: ahh Ok, then It is irrelevant to the fail of git clone no?

Comment: That's right. It looks like there's an error in your SSL config between git and nginx. I'm not sure what's causing it, sorry, but a quick search suggests a range of similar cases.

Comment: Thx!, we solve it, we redirect with netscaler to 8443 and fix it thank you very much! =)